# React floating prop warning without props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-dom

`application.js` (Entry point for webpack)

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App.jsx';

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'))
});
```

---

`App.jsx`

```
import React from 'react'
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route
} from 'react-router-dom'

import Navbar from './components/Navbar'
import LandingPage from './components/landingPage'
import Clients from './components/Clients'

class App extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Navbar />
          <Switch>
            <div className="container">
              <Route exact path="/app" component={LandingPage} />
              <Route exact path="/app/clients" component={Clients} />
            </div>
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
    )
  }
}
export default App
```

---

`components/LandingPage.jsx`

```
import React from 'react';

const LandingPage = (props) =>(
      <div>
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
      </div>
    )
export default LandingPage
```

---

`components/Clients.jsx`

```
import React from 'react';
class Clients extends React.Component {
  render(props) {
    return(
      <div id="clients" className="clients">
        <div className="row">
          Clients!
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default Clients
```

---

`components/Navbar.jsx`

```
import React from 'react'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';

const Navbar = (props) => (
  <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a className="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
     <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
       <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
     </button>
    <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul className="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li><Link to="/app/clients">GOTO CLIENTS</Link></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

)
export default Navbar
```

---

Error in console log:

> Warning: React does not recognize the `computedMatch` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `computedmatch` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.
>       in div (created by App)
>       in Switch (created by App)
>       in div (created by App)
>       in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
>       in BrowserRouter (created by App)
>       in App

I read in various other stack posts that this is a floating prop error when passing props around half-hazardly. However I am not passing any props here and am confused as to why this error is thrown. The app and components render fine too.

Any suggestion?

Comment: `computedMatch` doesn't appear anywhere in the code in your question. The question also has far too much code. Please update your question with a [mcve] (note the "minimal") demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: I know it doesn't appear in the code which is why I am so confused as to where that error is coming from (in combination with the app working fine). And I don't think it is too much code, the first two are the only required files as the second one is where the error is thrown. The other components are bare bones and are only added to pre-empt questions like "What about the components in the div the error points to?" since I don't use props inside them.  I see your point about the working example and will provide a codesandbox example.

Comment: *"...and will provide a codesandbox example."* No, that would be off-site. Make it an **on-site** example, as I said above.

Comment: Did my answer below solve your issue @Killerpixler?

Comment: @t-j-crowder It's resolved anyways now but it would need to be the offisite example to satisy the reproducability concern which is multiple files and import/exports

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `App.jsx`, you are specifying the `Switch` logic like this:

```
      <Switch>
        <div className="container">
          <Route exact path="/app" component={LandingPage} />
          <Route exact path="/app/clients" component={Clients} />
        </div>
      </Switch>
```

However, a `Switch` component only expects `Route` as its children. Remove the `<div className="container">` part and it should resolve this error message.

Comment: it does indeed. Thank you very much